# Disable Android Notification Bar in Full Screen (in SGIII)

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-notification-bar

In Samsung Galaxy S3, even though my app is set to be full screen, and this makes the notification bar not to be visible, if I swipe from the very edge of the screen side, this action will make the notification bar to appear again, allowing the user to expand it over the full screen app.
Is there any way to disable this, or to cancel the expand of the notification bar?
The problem is that I have a listview covering the whole screen, and if I swipe to scroll the items, every time I do it from the very edge due to the instinctive action of scrolling faster, then the notification bar appears again.
I've tried tricks such as creating an overlay window on the edge, but not working at all for SG3.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't tried already, you might attempt to use the `View` flag for hiding navigation, `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`, documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION).

However it may be important to note this found at the bottom of their description :

> There is a limitation: because navigation controls are so important, the least user interaction will cause them to reappear immediately. When this happens, both this flag and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN will be cleared automatically, so that both elements reappear at the same time.

which is probably related to what you're seeing. I find it hard to believe there's a way around this... I just tried and every fullscreen app I have on my S3 behaves this exact same way.

I suspect that if there was a way around it (assuming the above doesn't work, which I don't expect it to), it would be considered to be a bug by the Android team, and I would advise against it.